# Create Framework and Ambiguous reference to member 'log'

Tags: swift, xcode, logging, cocoapods

I'm having quite the time trying to turn my code into a Cocoapod / Framework.

So I have some code that I'd like to package into a framework (F) and then use that in App (A).  It is almost working, however, when I try to build A (who links F), where source in A references the log from F, I get an error

`Ambiguous reference to member 'log'`

This is because log is defined in my sources for F in a file named Logging.swift, and looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import XCGLogger

// MARK: - Logging

let log: XCGLogger = {
    let log = XCGLogger(identifier: "mainLogger", includeDefaultDestinations: false)

   // Create a destination for the system console log (via NSLog)
   let systemDestination = ConsoleDestination(identifier: log.identifier+".console")

   // configure it here, omitted for brevity

   // Add the destination to the logger
  log.add(destination: systemDestination)

  // Add basic app info, version info etc, to the start of the logs
  log.logAppDetails()

  return log
}()
```

My questions are:

i) How do I get rid of this error?  I'm guessing it has something to do with specifying which module is logging this, because there are other modules that also have a log.  (Darwin, CoreGraphics, etc.)

ii) How do I set up my logging so that anything that would be logged in framework F code could also be included in the same logger for App A ?  Is that even possible or necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I can now answer my own question:

I changed the Framework's Logging.swift file to:

```
public struct Log {

  public static var main: XCGLogger = {
      let log = XCGLogger(identifier: "mainLogger", includeDefaultDestinations: false)

      // Create a destination for the system console log (via NSLog)
      let systemDestination = ConsoleDestination(identifier: log.identifier+".console")

      // Optionally set some configuration options (omitted for brevity)

      // Add the destination to the logger
      log.add(destination: systemDestination)

      // Add basic app info, version info etc, to the start of the logs
      log.logAppDetails()

      return log
  }()
}
```

Then it has a default logger.  I reference calls to the log with Log.main

In my Application A, I can define my own logger, and just assign it:

`Log.main = myOtherLog`